# Can "ultra vires" mean "without authorization"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, idiom, legal-latin

The legal term *ultra virēs* literally means "beyond their powers"; it refers to, say, a government official trying to make a law they don't have the authority to make (making that law is "beyond their powers").

I recently saw it used in conversation to mean "without permission" in a more casual sense, like saying students can't submit assignments late without permission. I can see the connection—permission to submit an assignment late is an authorization to do something, which could fall under *virēs*. But it does strike me as a somewhat odd use of the phrase.

Is this a valid use of *ultra virēs*, as in, one that would be idiomatic at some stage of the language? If not, what would be a better way to refer to the less formal permission a student gets from a professor? I'm vaguely recalling some idiom involving *numen*, or some other word for "nod", but not with enough specificity to look it up.

Comment: As a result of this, I'm also curious whether _virēs_ makes a good translation for "permissions" in the technical sense, like an account having the right permissions to make files, or a StackExchange user having access to close votes. But that's a separate question.

Comment: What about "absque permissu"? Absque can be used like a juridic formula to express "without.

Comment: @ManuelCauãRebouças It's post-classical, but you do get that exact phrase a couple times, once in Justinian's Code and once in Bede. *Sine permissu* is much better attested, even if still rather late (middle 2nd century CE in Gaius' *Institutiones*).

Comment: @Draconis: There is a linkage between "beyond one's powers" & "without permission". He who lacks the power/ authority, to do this-or-that, may also lack the permission from his bosses/ his electorate. I've seen translations in which the translator has pushed the barriers of credulity to breaking point. At least this one has a logical sequence to it.

Comment: @tony Yeah, I definitely see the logic to it; I'm just not sure if it's the proper idiom for this, or if the Romans (or post-Classical authors) would have used some other term for, say, a son doing something without his paterfamilias's permission.